# Different Contributions if a member

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

Is it possible to configure a contribution page or amount to be different if the person is a member?

For example, members pay $20 and non-members pay $25 as a contribution (its a separate registration fee, not a member fee in that sense).

Thanks
Norm

Answer (score 1):

Yep - you can use CiviCRM Discount extensions for that; however - for registration fees -> you would need to use CiviEvent. Discounts don't work on Contributions/Donations;

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in this scenario - I need it to be a contribution.  I may have to write something then.

Comment: To mold registration fees into a contribution is like coding uphill - there will not be many people wanting to do it that way. I even wonder if CiviDiscount would accept a PR that made it possible to discount a contribution - so you're not just on your own to code it - but also to maintain it; I recommend you try mold your use case into the typical/out of the box scenario where registration fees are collected using CiviEvent.

Comment: It's not a registration in the sense of CiviMember.  I have a list of contacts with a set of multi-value custom fields.  We charge the contact a fee for recording a dog into their profile. The issue is if that contact was also a member, their fee is less.

Comment: Are you using Drupal? You can discount Contributions using Webform CiviCRM module

Comment: Wordpress and CiviCRM - both latest versions. That same option, however, may be available in Caldera Forms, which I use.  I will investigate that.